# How to join two queries to make a subquery

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, substring, sql-max

I have a first query that give me a set of values and a second query that give me the maximum of this set of value.
I want to merge these two queries. I tried like this below:

First query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column, INSTR(column, ' ')+1,3)  
from table  
WHERE column LIKE '#13 %'
```

Second query:

```
SELECT MAX(column)
```

The merge:

```
SELECT MAX(column) 
FROM table WHERE column = (
  SELECT  SUBSTR(column, INSTR(column, ' ')+1,3)  
  from table  
  WHERE column LIKE '#13 %'
)
```

Can you please help how can I merge two queries?

First query result:

```
30
1
2
3
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

I want to have the maximum value of this set of values with my second query: `30`.

Comment: What do you mean by *merge*? Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I use python and sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `SUBSTR(column, INSTR(column, ' ') + 1, 3)` is a string, so you must cast it to a number and this can be done simply by adding `0`.
Then use `MAX()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(column, INSTR(column, ' ') + 1, 3) + 0)  
FROM tablename  
WHERE column LIKE '#13 %';
```

Since you have the condition `column LIKE '#13 %'` in the `WHERE` clause, then you know that the 1st space in the column is at position 4, so you could simplify to:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(column, 5, 3) + 0)  
FROM tablename  
WHERE column LIKE '#13 %';
```